# JS not executing on page loaded with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I'm working on a single page application website. All the navigation happens inside a div. I use addEventListener click to find the link, prevent regular href and open it inside the div.

With this code I can change pages, keeping the head and footer without refresh the entire page.

```
var spa_array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spa')); // Array with history (for the back button)

spa_array.forEach( function(b) {
    var id = b.id;
    b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent href
        history.pushState({id:id}, null, id); // Change url on browser
        openPage(id);
    });
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
    openPage(e.state.id);
});

function openPage(url) {
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url);
    $("#spa").load(encodedUrl); // open link inside the div
}
```

This is where the problem happens: I use JS to load a new page on the div, index_2.html for example. The links on index_2.html page will not trigger the JS addEventListener, so it will refresh the page and open the new link.

JS is not being applied to the page opened inside the .load. Is there a way to apply the same script, without calling it again (which causes many a lot of trouble)?

Comment: You don't need to reattach event listener every time you reload the content. Just listen the 'click' event of the host element (#spa). Due to the "bubbling" you'll get all 'click' events of child elements inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler:

```
$("#spa").on('click', '.spa', function(e){
    var anchor = this,
        id = anchor.id;
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState({id:id}, null, id);
    openPage(id);
});
```

You can register the handler on a DOM node that does not get removed (in your case, the container whose contents change, but the element itself stays the same), and pass in a selector as a second argument to check if the click occurred on an element inside it that matches the selector.

This is necessary because once you `.load()` additional content it will replace whatever was there in the element before, including any event listeners that you attached, once, on first load. You'd need to call your loop each time the content is changed, but this is a much less resource intensive solution that will save you the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the logic for adding the event listeners as shown below:

```
function bindLinks() {
  var spa_array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spa'));
  spa_array.forEach( function(b) {
    var id = b.id;
    b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent href
      history.pushState({id:id}, null, id); // Change url on browser
      openPage(id);
    });
  });
}
```

That way you can call `bindLinks()` after the html is loaded into your div. You can do that by passing it as the second argument to `.load()`.

```
function openPage(url) {
  var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url);
  $("#spa").load(encodedUrl, bindLinks);
}
```